# Is it a sufficient condition for linearity?

Tags: real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, matrices, matrix-analysis

Edit: According to the comment by LSpice we come back to the initial version of this question

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^n$ be  a smooth function such that for every $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ the derivative $A=Df(x)$ satisfies the condition $a_{ii}=1$ and $a_{ij}=k(x),\; \forall i\neq j$ where $k(x)$ depends only on $x$. Does it imply that $f $ is  a  linear map?

A some what similar form of this linear part is considered here

https://qr.ae/pNsOY1

Comment: If $f$ were linear its differential would be constant, so your $k(x)$ actually cannot depend on $x$ if you believe your claim to be true. Or am I missing smomething?

Comment: @leomonsaingeon  you are right but in the question we do not assume $k(x)$ is constant. BTW please read the revised version since I insist that the linear part would be ientified to the original quora question.

Comment: @leomonsaingeon In the other word is there a  non linear map whose pointwise linear part is in the form of linked quora question?

Comment: Questions should be self contained.  I think it would be particularly desireable in this case to include whatever is relevant from the Quora question, because it's not clear, at least to me:  are you imposing an extra hypothesis, or referring us (for some reason) to a computation of a determinant, or something else?

Comment: @LSpice  I think the question is clear. The quora link is added just to keep a kind of copy rigth because that quora question leads me to arrive at this question. I do not understand  why the question is not self contained?

Comment: It's not clear what the significance of the off-diagonal entries is; if you consider instead $g$, where the $i$th component function of $g$ is $x \mapsto f_i(x) - \sum_{j \ne i} x_j$, then $Dg(x)$ is everywhere scalar, so you might as well ask whether a function with everywhere-scalar derivative is linear.

Comment: I don't know if the question is self contained, because you [say](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/368106/is-it-a-sufficient-condition-for-linearity#comment928590_368106) "I insist that the linear part would be i[d]entified to the original quora question".  Since you asked for a re-reading on that basis, I assumed you were meaning to add additional information.

Comment: Also, notice that your hypothesis on the derivative is always satisfied when $n = 1$.

Comment: @LSpice  yes you are right. May be this is the  reason that in the first version of the question I  considered the case $a_{ii}=1$ and $a_{ij}=k(x)$.

Comment: @LSpice The first version was the question originaly aroused me a few days ago

Comment: @LSpice Thank you for your attention.I revise the question

Comment: @LSpice  If  I would not refere to the quora question, I am almost sure that a participant would comment "from where you arrive at this form of linear part?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I answer the version where you assume that the diagonal entries of $Df$ are constant (all $1$, in your problem), and the off-diagonal entries of each $Df(x)$ are all the same value $k(x)$.

I assume that, by linear, you mean affine linear.  Then this is clear if $n = 1$.  Otherwise, fix $i$, let $f_i$ be the appropriate component function of $f$, and choose any $j \ne i$.  Since $k$ equals $\frac\partial{\partial x_j}f_i$ and $\frac\partial{\partial x_i}f_i$ equals $1$, we have that $\frac\partial{\partial x_i}k = \frac\partial{\partial x_j}1 = 0$.  That is, $k$ is constant, so $Df$ is constant, so $f$ is affine linear.

Comment: thank you very much  for your answer. Actually you answered both version as you indicated in your comment for n=1.

Comment: Is it  easy to classify all smooth maps whose derivative A satisfies  $a_{ii}=L(x)$ and $a_{ij}=K(x)$?

Comment: I don't know, but, at least for $n \ge 3$, we do have by the same trick that all partial derivatives of $L$ are equal, all partial derivatives of $K$ are equal, and they are all equal to each other.

Comment: (Note again that your new condition is no restriction when $n = 1$.)

Comment: @AliTaghavi, given a smooth map $f$ like [that](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/368106/is-it-a-sufficient-condition-for-linearity/368109#comment928609_368109), replace $f$ by $f - f(0)$ so $f(0) = 0$, then consider $F$ with component functions $F_i \colon x \mapsto \frac1{n!}\sum_{\sigma \in \operatorname S_n} f_{\sigma i}(\sigma x)$. Then $DF$ equals $Df$ everywhere and $F(0) = 0 = f(0)$, so $F = f$.  So I think: those functions that, after normalised by $f(0) = 0$, satisfy $f_i(x) = f_{\sigma i}(\sigma x)$, with appropriate quantification. (No condition for $n = 1$, as it should(n't) be.)